# Moving Averages in Data frame by factor variable with non-leading NA's and entire factor levels as NA's in R

Tags: r, plyr

I haven't found satisfactory answers on how to calculate moving averages in a data frame by a factor variable. Also, I have the problem of entire factor levels being NA (no data for one country or individual) and the case of non-leading NA's (last observation is missing).

Consider:

```
value <- c(rep(NA,4),1,2,3,NA,5:8)
factor <- c(rep("a",4), rep("b",4),rep("c",4))
Data <- as.data.frame(cbind(value,factor))
```

I would like to have a (right aligned) moving average over 3 observations. Sorry about the packages but in my mind, this should work with a ddply function along these lines:

```
library(TTR) # for moving averages
library(plyr) # for ddply
Data <- ddply(Data,"factor",MAvalue = SMA(value, n=3))
```

The result should look like this:

```
value    factor    MAvalue
NA       a         NA
NA       a         NA
NA       a         NA
NA       a         NA # this factor has no data
1        b         NA
2        b         NA
3        b         2
NA       b         NA # this factor is missing the last observation
5        c         NA
6        c         NA
7        c         6
8        c         7 # this factor has complete information
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

with the NA data :

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

setDT(Data)
Data[, MA.value := rollmeanr(value, 3, na.pad = TRUE), by = factor]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the cases where there are factors which are all NA. It does not work for cases with non-leading NA's, however. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I updated my question concerning the NA issues and will delete my comments after we solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

When using `cbind`, it converts all of the data to character.  Try this.

```
value <- c(1:12)
factor <- c(rep("a",6), rep("b",6))
Data <- data.frame(factor = factor,
                      value = value)

ddply(Data, .(factor), transform, MAValue = SMA(value, 3))

   factor value MAValue
1       a     1      NA
2       a     2      NA
3       a     3       2
4       a     4       3
5       a     5       4
6       a     6       5
7       b     7      NA
8       b     8      NA
9       b     9       8
10      b    10       9
11      b    11      10
12      b    12      11
```

Comment: Thanks! That Works so far. How can I deal with one factor level being completely NA? That returns an error right now. For example replace 'value' with: value <- c(rep(NA,6),7:12)

Comment: I realize that most of my problems come from NA's. This code seems to have a problem with both non-leading NA's (it doesn't understand that it can just stop one obs earlier when the last obs is missin) and with factor levels that are all NA's (which it should just return as NA's). Would you mind if I update my question along these lines? We can delete our comments afterwards

Comment: Combining what Henk did above, but not using data.tables, try `library(zoo);ddply(Data, .(factor), transform, rollmean(value,3))`

Comment: You can/should also specify what sort of moving average you want. See ?rollmean for options [center, left, right].